# Change height of embedded iframe youtubevid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, iframe

I want to change the height of an embedded  youtube vid. I've read many threads where the solution seems to be adding an extra div outside the iframe element. My problem is that the  element is fetched from the backend and already inside p tag.

this is my html

```
    <p class="richTextBox" ng-bind-html="getHtml(question.answer)"></p>
```

[image: This is what is fetched from the backend]

How can i use css to change the iframe embedded in the ng-bind-html? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some code snipped on fiddle or a snapshot of the output with F12 Elements open.  I think increasing the height of P tag should work.

Comment: Updated the question with a snapshot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="container">
  <iframe src="" frameborder="0" width=100%; height= 100% ></iframe>
</p>


.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Try This should work. As Iframe will take the parent's height and width.